# Convergence in law of point processes implies pointwise convergence?

Tags: probability-theory

Let me first set up what I mean by convergence in law of a point process. I'm interested here in simple, locally finite point processes on a complete, separable metric space $X$. And by a point process I mean a random, discrete measure on $X$.

Let $M$ be the space of locally finite, discrete, simple measures on $X$ and give it the topology of vague convergence. Ie.,  $\mu_n \to \mu$ if for every continuous $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support,
$$
\int f(x) d\mu_n(x) \to \int f(x) d\mu(x).
$$

Now say the sequence of **random** point processes $\mu_n$ converges in law to $\mu$ if they converge weakly with respect to the vague topology. Ie., for every continuous bounded function $F: M \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathbb{E} F(\mu_n) \to \mathbb{E}F(\mu).
$$

Finally, to my question. If $\mu_n$ converges in law to $\mu$, is it true that there exists a realization of these point processes on a probability space such that on compact sets the point processes converge almost surely? So if $P_n$ are the points in $X$ corresponding to $\mu_n$, $P$ are the points in $X$ corresponding to $\mu$, and $K \subset X$ is compact, is it true that
$$
\lim d( P_n \cap K, P \cap K) = 0 \, a.s., 
$$
where $d$ is the usual notion of distance between two sets? This seems like a Skorokhod type of result so I expect that it's true but I can't find a reference or prove it myself.